# Android Help: Boolean and SqLite?

Tags: android

I cant find out how to save boolean array into sqlite. I dont think you can but im using boolean array for setmulichoiceitems and it wont let me use anything else than boolean arary so how would i save it to a database. couldi covert boolean array to string or something some how

```
boolean[]   states = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false};

final CharSequence[] items = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddTimeEntry.this);
                      builder.setTitle("Repeat");
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
                    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, states, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item, boolean go) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use TEXT and set it to "true" or "false" and then use

```
if(string.matches("true")){
    boolean = true;
} else {
    boolean = false;
}
```

EDIT To convert the boolean back to a string use

```
if (boolean == true){
    string = "true";
} else {
    string = "false";
}
```

if you want to use an int then

```
if(int == 1){
    boolean = true;
} else {
    boolean = false;
}
```

and

```
if (boolean == true){
    int = 1;
} else {
    int = 0;
}
```

EDIT 2 A string array is added to by `string[0] = "text to add"` or you can add them when you declare is

```
String[] string = { "string1", "string2", "string3" }
```

Comment: Thanks one more question i have ever use text array before so how to i use it and add stuff into it?

Comment: i get error saying im only allow use boolean with builder.setMultiChoiceItems?

Comment: then pass it the boolean variable

Answer (score 0):

You can store is as an integer 0 for false and 1 for true.
Convert them to boolean in the code

Comment: How do i covert  from boolean to int to use 0 and 1 and then back to boolean in the code?